# Error while hitting a API

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I am hitting a API for push notification and it is giving me error.
I am passing parameter as a string in API like this:

```
NSString * jsonString= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"device_id\":%@,\"device_type\":I,\"regId\":%@}",[AppDelega‌​te getMacAddress],deviceToken];
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
[manager POST:kNotificationURL 
   parameters:jsonString 
     progress:nil
      success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
                NSLog(@"notification JSON: %@", responseObject);
                NSDictionary *json = [Utility cleanJsonToObject:responseObject];
                NSError * err;
                NSData * jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:json
                                                                    options:0
                                                                      error:&err];
                NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                                                     options:kNilOptions
                                                                       error:&err];
                NSLog(@"the data is %@",dict);
               }
               failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
                         NSLog(@" notification Error: %@", error);
               }];
```

The error I am getting:

```
Response :Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
```

please let me know, what have i do wrong

Comment: this is my json string which i am passing

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty fix would be to try this, although building your own JSON string isn't a good idea.  Look at using [JSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/)

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"device_id\":\"%@\",\"device_type\":\"I\",\"regId\":\"%@\"}",[AppDelega‌​te getMacAddress],deviceToken];
```